# A certain page won't load after deployment

Tags: vue.js, heroku

I deployed my personal website using VueJs and Heroku.  While you can see the homepage, when I click on the button that would take me to the Current Projects page, I get the following error :

> "Cannot GET /CurrentProjects".

I can see this page on localhost, but not live.   Has this ever happened to anyone?  If so, what should I be looking out for. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried clearing out your browser cache? try `Command + Shift + R` on Mac or `Ctrl + Shift + R` on Windows. Also, it will be helpful if you can share your `nuxt.config.js` file.

Comment: @emare. I did try clearing out the cache, but not luck.  Where is the nuxt.confg.js file located?